# Interacting with a dynamically created EditText in a fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm using the title strips + sliding template that's in Eclipse's activity creator. Here's my fragment code:

```java
   public static class FactorFragment extends Fragment {

    static EditText numHolder;
    Button btnFactor;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Activity me = getActivity();
        // Create the layout
        // Create the views
        RelativeLayout holder = new RelativeLayout(me);
        numHolder = new EditText(me);
        numHolder.setId(1);
        btnFactor = new Button(me);
        btnFactor.setId(2);
        // Style the RelativeLayout
        holder.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        // Style the EditText
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams edittext = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        edittext.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, btnFactor.getId());
        edittext.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        edittext.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, btnFactor.getId());
        numHolder.setEms(10);
        numHolder.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        numHolder.setLayoutParams(edittext);
        // Style the button
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        btn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        btn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        btnFactor.setText("Factor");
        btnFactor.setLayoutParams(btn);
        btnFactor.setOnClickListener(onClick);
        // Add them to the layout
        holder.addView(numHolder);
        holder.addView(btnFactor);
        return holder;
    }

    static OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(numHolder.getText().toString());
            Log.e("hi", Integer.toString(num));
        }
    };
}
```

As you can see, I'm creating an EditText called numHolder that will hold numerical values. The problem I'm having is that when I click on the button, I get a force close error on this line:

```
    Log.e("hi", Integer.toString(num));
```

LogCat is telling me that `Integer.toString()` can't parse empty strings. However, from the fact that I get the contents of the EditText in the line above that, this leads me to believe that either 1) I'm using the wrong method to get the number from the EditText or 2) numHolder is for some reason not available to use.

What's going wrong? I've been trying to figure this out for hours.

**EDIT**:

I removed `static` from the `EditText` and the `onClickListener`. It seems to work now.

Comment: Why are you making the `EditText` and the `Listener` static? And why don't you use xml for this? It seems easier.

Comment: I'm making the EditText static because Java wouldn't let me edit it otherwise. I'm not using XML for this because I need to dynamically create the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `numHolder.getText().toString()` to get the contents of the EditText numHolder.

You should first check the contents of the EditText before converting it to integer.

```
int num = 0;
try {
  String numText = numHolder.getText().toString();
  Log.d("Hi", "Text obtained is: " + numText);
  num = Integer.parseInt(numText);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // Handle exception
}
Log.e("hi", Integer.toString(num));
```

Comment: I changed it to this, I'm still getting the error. Specifically, 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""'

Comment: That means the text you entered in the EditText is not an integer. First check if the text is an integer before using Integer.parseInt()

Comment: Always surround parsing with `try/catch` blocks, you never know how the user will make it fail.

Comment: The only thing you *can* enter is an integer - the inputType of the EditText is "InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER". And I'm making sure to input numbers in the EditText before pressing the button.

Comment: The error you posted says that it obtained "" from edittext which means the edit text did not have any text entered. Even though the edittext is only of numbers, there are scenarios which it fails: If no user input is given, and if wrong input given. (Ex: 45.)

Comment: I am making sure to use a valid number. In my tests, I use the number 55. One thing to note is that the keyboard changes to the number keyboard when I press the EditText. Could that be it?